# How to test CSS Framework custom components with vue-test-utils

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, vue.js, vue-test-utils, buefy

I'm using the Buefy CSS Framework, which provides custom vue-js components such as `<b-input>` and `<b-table>`, and I've come across a problem testing the `<b-input>` tag.

```js
import { shallowMount, createLocalVue } from '@vue/test-utils'
import BInputPractice from '../BInputPractice.vue'
import Buefy from 'buefy'

const localVue = createLocalVue()
localVue.use(Buefy)

describe('b-input Practice', () => {
  it('updates the name data property', () => {
    const wrapper = shallowMount(BInputPractice, { 
      localVue,
      stubs: {
        'b-input': Buefy.Input
      } 
    })
    const input = wrapper.find('input')
    input.element.value = 'a name'
    input.trigger('input')
    expect(wrapper.vm.name).toBe('a name')
  })
})
```

```html
<!-- BInputPractice.vue -->
<template>
  <div>
    <b-input v-model="name"></b-input>
    <!-- <input v-model="name"> -->
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        name: ''
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

The expect statement in my test code should pass, as it passes when I use an `<input>` tag instead of a `<b-input>`. However, triggering the 'input' event on the `<b-input>` does nothing to the `name` data property.

[image]

Does anyone know how I can correctly stub the `<b-input>` tag so that I can test it exactly as an `<input>` tag?

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will help a bit. I realised that when stubbed, a component's name change and `-stub` is added at the end.

So if you stub `b-input` it will be called `b-input-stub` when using:

```
const wrapper = shallowMount(BInputPractice, { stubs: ['b-input'] })
```

I don't thing you need to use `localView` and `stubs` at the same time. Also you can use the [setData(data)](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/wrapper/#setdata-data) to set the data of a component.

```
expect(wrapper.find('b-input-stub').exists()).toBeTruthy() 
wrapper.setData({ name: 'a name' })
expect(wrapper.vm.name).toEqual('a name')
```

Here the `trigger('input')` does not need to be launched because you didn't specify something to do `@input.native` in the `b-input` like in the template:

```
<b-input @input.native="updateName" v-model="name"> </b-input>
```

And inside the export default in your script.

```
methods: {
    updateName: function () {
      this.$emit('nameUpdate', this.name)
    }
  }
```

However to set and validate the value of custom components like `b-input`, I would refer to [vuejs/vue-test-utils](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-test-utils/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=b-input).